# Insertion Failed:Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables- users and language with a foreign key link of their primary key 'id'.
I have checked that the type is innoDB for the tables. I have delete- restrict and update -cascade.

This insert query, inserts it into the language table: (it can be more than one row which is added as the form has dynamic clickevent button)

```
if(empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) { // user not logged in; redirect to somewhere else }

$sql_insert = "INSERT into `language`
 (`native`,`other`,`other_list`,`other_read`, `other_spokint`
 ,`other_spokprod`,`other_writ`  )
VALUES
 ('$native','$other','$other_list','$other_read','$other_spokint','$other_spokprod',
 '$other_writ') ";

mysql_query($sql_insert,$link) or die("Insertion Failed:" . mysql_error());     
}
```

This is the full error:

```
Insertion Failed:Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`members`.`language`, CONSTRAINT `language_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) 
REFERENCES `users` (`id`))
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Table structure for table language:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `language` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `native` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `other` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `other_list` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
 `other_read` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
 `other_spokint` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
 `other_spokprod` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
 `other_writ` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;


RELATIONS FOR TABLE `language`:
`id`
`users` -> `id`
```

Comment: The error message says there is a foreign key problem for your ID fild. Did you check that a user with the ID exists in your users table?

Comment: How an auto incremented field "id" of language table can be mapped a foreign key "id" field of user table?

Comment: yes I am struggling with how to link the tables and what to use for primary keys. What would be the best solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a structure like this:

```
create table users (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    <additional fields>,

    primary key (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


create table language(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    user_id int not null,
    <additional fields>,

    primary key (id),
    foreign key (user_id) references users(id) on delete restrict on update cascade
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: I've done that and still getting error: 'Insertion Failed:Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`members`.`language`, CONSTRAINT `language_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)'

Comment: isn't it because you are not providing a user_id in your insert?  If the foreign key is defined as `not null`, you have to provide it in your insert

Comment: But the user ID will be different each insert?

Comment: I want the id in the user table to be the same as user_id in language

Comment: I don't know what you want to do but from your code above, it looks like your getting the user_id or redirecting to login page (or else).  If you have a field in table language that is linked to table users by a user_id, then everytime your inserting into language, you have to provide the user_id.  I suppose the rows in language concern a user in particular...

Comment: your insert should then look like: `insert into language(user_id,native,other,other_list,other_read, other_spokint,other_spokprod,other_writ) VALUES ($user_id, ...)`

Comment: Then you have to provide infos on your user.  How is mysql supposed to know which user your are inserting row in language for?  Either provide the user_id (same as id in users table), or use a subquery like `insert into language (user_id,...) values ((select user_id from users where user_name=...),...)` or something like this.

Comment: So how would I provide the user_id to be the same ad id in users table? sorry to be a pain!I'm learning!

Comment: in your user's session, you must have infos on the user connected to your application, am I right?  If not, when your doing an insert, then user must provide infos about himself, but this is not a good way to manage users.  For each user session your are creating, you must check in your database if the user exists (some kind of login...)

Comment: Then when the user logs in, I guess you are querying the database to get his id, firstname, lastname, etc...  What we usually do is put all this infos in the session object.  Then each time the user does an action, you know the user id, name, etc...  What is in `$_SESSION['user_id']` ?

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't put anything in the $_SESSION. Thanks for your help!